# Google Analytics Data API (GA4)- IsDataGolden flag

Tags: google-api

When data was requested through Universal Analytic API, response can contain flag IsDataGolden. If IsDataGolden = False, It is mean that this data can be changed.
Can GA4 API contain the same flag or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData) which extracts data for Universal analytics accounts

[image]

IsDataGolden = False means that the data has not completed processing internally.  It does not mean that the data changed be changed.  No data within Google analytics can be changed once you have inserted the hit.

No [Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) does not support this future.  Currently this api is still in beta it may be added in the future though there is no way to know.